# Checking for a 'sticky post' type

Tags: wordpress, loops, implementation, app-themes

I am working on "classipress" (a wordpress theme) and I am intend to make that feature (sticky post) come up on the top of the category.

Thus far I have obtained the result needed by using the below script, so for this classipress have two files which deals with category ad lisitng:

1. taxonomy-ad_cat.php
2. loop-ad_listing

`taxonomy-ad_cat.php` actually passes the current category & calls `the loop-ad_listing` of that category so I initially call only the sticky post and then call post except of sticky by using below code:

```
query_posts( array('post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE, APP_TAX_CAT => $term->slug, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'paged' => $paged, 'post__in' => get_option('sticky_posts')) );
loop hoes here...
```

The problem is that I  want to check within `loop-ad_listing.php` that the `post__in` is sticky or  not , because when (as an example) a category currently  doesn't have the listing and it shows the empty message twice. Once for the sticky calling loop & a second for absence of sticky calling loop..

Can you help me implement this correctly in to my posted code based on my description?

Comment: no clue for solving this...???

Comment: ok i got the solution..:) i will upload it affter 6 hours..as stack flow restric me to post now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Coool...I got the the solution...

i made another file which is *loop-ad_listing1.php* & in that file i only check if dont have the post show empty message & in the original file which call for the loop whcih is *loop-ad_listing.php* ... i remove empty message from it...

So what i achieve is,

if i have the ad listings on that page my alternative file show nothing & orignal file shows listing & if dont have ad lisitngs than my duplicate file shows empty message while original file donot show any thing.. cool:)

While the above mentioned Mihai Stancu trick will also work & preferable if we have only one file for listings.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use:

```
While(has_post()): the_post();
    If(is_sticky()):
    Else:
    Endif;
Endwhile;
```

Comment: yes Mihai thats nice idea...but i use this for highlight too:)...i want to post answer but now i am restricted because of stackover flow rules

Comment: The above solution is good & preferable for if we have a single file for loop & category listing..